# Can we check the request count in web logic console?

Tags: ejb, weblogic

Literally a dumb question,

I am using a ejb with Web logic server.  Whenever someone hits this ejb, can we see the request count to the server in weblogic console (Once logged in under tab Environments----> Servers, under servers can I see how many ejb requests this [server] has got) ? If not in weblogic console, is there any way to check this ?
My main goal here is to check if my code is hitting the [server] ejb or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this from access.log It would be available at below location.

```
    <DOMAIN_HOME>/servers/<server-name>/logs/access.log
```